# *ngFor causing charJs charts to flicker (even with .destroy())

Tags: typescript, chart.js, angular9

I'm using Angular 9 and chartJs 2.9.3.
I got into an issue where charts starts flickering when toggling between multiple using same canvas and .destroy() function. Strangely, this happens when *ngFor is specified in html and they wont flicker when *ngFor is removed. I'm unsure if the issue is because angular, chartJS or any implementation anomaly. Below is the code:

Typescript:

```
  companies: any[];
  selectedCompany: any;
  charts: any[] = [];
  isCollapsed: boolean[] = [];
  ESGSplit: any[] = [];
  canvases: any; 

  @ViewChildren('mycharts', { read: ElementRef }) chartElementRefs: QueryList<ElementRef>; 

  
  //Method used to change charts after loaded initially.
  changeChartType(index, chartType) {
    this.charts[index].chart.destroy();
    let kpi = this.charts[index].kpi
    var chartData = this.chartBuilderService.buildChart(chartType, kpi);  
    var chart = new Chart(this.canvases._results[index].nativeElement.getContext('2d'), chartData)
    this.charts[index].chart = chart
  }

  //Method used to load charts on init
  loadCompanyData(company) {
   
    this.selectedCompany = company
    this.backendService.getCompanyKpisData(company).subscribe(async (data) => {
      this.charts = [];
      Object.values(data)[0].forEach((kpi) => {
        this.charts.push({
          kpi: kpi
        }
        );
      })

      this.chartElementRefs.changes.subscribe((elementRefs) => {
        this.canvases = elementRefs

        this.canvases.map((canvas, indx) => {   // For each canvas, save the chart on the charts array 
          let kpi = this.charts[indx].kpi

          if(this.ESGSplit.indexOf(kpi.ESG) === -1) {
            this.ESGSplit.push(kpi.ESG);
          }

          let chartTypes = this.chartBuilderService.supportedCharttypesForKPi(kpi) 

          console.log(chartTypes)
          let chartData = this.chartBuilderService.buildChart(chartTypes[0], kpi)
          var chart = new Chart(canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d'), chartData)
          this.charts[indx].chart = chart
          this.charts[indx].types = chartTypes
        })
    
      });
  })

  }
```

Here is the html:

```
    <body>

  <div class="content-wrapper">

    <section class="row">

      <div class="col-3">

        <div class="card hoverable" *ngIf="ESGSplit.length != 0">

          <div class="sidebar">

            <div class="sideNav" *ngFor="let eachESG of ESGSplit; let j = index">

              <label class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="isCollapsed[j] = !isCollapsed[j]" role="button"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                {{eachESG}}
              </label>

              <div *ngFor="let chart of charts; let i = index">

                <div *ngIf="chart.kpi.ESG == eachESG">
                  <div [collapse]="isCollapsed[j]">
                    <a class=" angular-with-newlines" (click)="scrollToChart(i)"> {{chart.kpi.title}}</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-9 d-flex flex-column">

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row mt-5" *ngFor="let chart of charts; let i = index">
            <div class="col-sm-12" id="item-{{i}}">
              <div class="card hoverable">

                <div class="card-head">
                  <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="btn-group" id="pullleft">
                      <button data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-sm">
                        <i class="fas fa-signal"></i>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menuChoices" role="menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeChartType(i, type);"
                            *ngFor="let type of chart.types">{{type.title}}</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div id="parent-canvas" class="card-body">

                  <canvas id="mychart{{i}}" #mycharts></canvas>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>


  </div>

</body>
```

Finally, *ngFor that is causing the issue in the above html. Without the below specified *ngFor the charts won't flicker. Please note that there are other *ngFor in html apart for the specified below with which the flicker is never encountered.

```
 <div class="sideNav" *ngFor="let eachESG of ESGSplit; let j = index">

              <label class="dropdown-toggle" (click)="isCollapsed[j] = !isCollapsed[j]" role="button"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                {{eachESG}}
              </label>

              <div *ngFor="let chart of charts; let i = index">

                <div *ngIf="chart.kpi.ESG == eachESG">
                  <div [collapse]="isCollapsed[j]">
                    <a class=" angular-with-newlines" (click)="scrollToChart(i)"> {{chart.kpi.title}}</a>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

            </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi yer1510 and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be easier for us to identify what's wrong, if you could boil down your code to just the important bits.

Comment: Hi @Reynicke, thank you for looking into this and feedback. I have truncated some part of the code. Now, the provided contains only the code related to issue. Thanks